# Facebook.init method not executing

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I'm a total noob using the Facebook Graph API for AS3. I have a Flash game and the idea is to upload it to Facebook, and everything seems to be ok (When entering the Facebook app, the swf shows perfectly and I'm able to post the facebook user id, the user name and the score to a database in the server where the game is located. I intend the game to automatically post to the user feed what he/she had score, but after making a lot of tests I found out that the method is simply not running.

Here is a sample of the .as file that tries to post the score to the user's news feed:

```
    package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;

    public class GameOver extends MovieClip
    {
        private var user_id : String = "";
        private var user_name : String = "";

        // these are the api and secret keys you should be used to
        var api_key:String="MY_API_KEY";



        function GameOver()
        {
            var newscore = Main.scorenum;
            finalScore.text = newscore;
            getFacebookID();
            Facebook.init(api_key);
            var opts:Object = {scope:"publish_stream, email"};
            Facebook.login(onLogin,opts);

        }           

        function onLogin(session:Object, fail:Object):void 
        {
            if(session!=null)
            {
                post();             
            }
            else
            {
                trace("Login Failed");
            }
        }

        public function post():void
        {
            var params:Object = new Object;
            //params.access_token = Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken;
            params.message = 'Hello World';
            params.caption = "Hello World";
            params.description = "Hello World";
            params.picture="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-0Hn3AjTJj6U/TZHe3ragXGI/AAAAAAAAA1M/_SBk3dx61EE/s1600/med_funny-cat.jpg";
            params.name="Hello World";
            params.link="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-0Hn3AjTJj6U/TZHe3ragXGI/AAAAAAAAA1M/_SBk3dx61EE/s1600/med_funny-cat.jpg";
            var methodInput = 'feed';           
            Facebook.api("/"+user_id+"/feed",submitPostHandler,params,"POST");
        }

        private function submitPostHandler(result:Object, fail:Object):void {
            trace("\n\nRESULT:\n" + JSON.encode(result));
            puntajeFinal.text = "RESULT:" + JSON.encode(result) + user_name;
        }
```

And here is the php file where the .swf is posted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="chimpInvader">
            <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
</div>
<div id="flashContent">
<!--<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="600" height="700">
  <param name="SRC" value="chimpInvader.swf" />
  <embed src="chimpInvader.swf" width="600" height="700" />
</object>-->
</div>
<script>
FB.init({appId  : '336824736350079', status : true, cookie : true, xfbml  : true });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(false);
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 720, width: 600 });
    swfobject.embedSWF("chimpInvader.swf", "chimpInvader", "600", "700", "11.1", null, null, null, null);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I wish you could help me, sorry for my lousy english.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Facebook javascript library to authenticate the user with facebook. 
So to make you app work with flash, you need to have the javascript API request additional permissions to publish a story to the user's feed.

When you request the extended permissions, and the user grants them, the javascript api will return an access token. It will be a long string. Pass this string into flash, as flash will need to include this access token when posting the news story to facebook.

Below is the way I like to achive this when I use facebook and flash together.

```
<script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script>
        // make it safe to use console.log always
        (function(b){function c(){}for(var d="assert,count,debug,dir,dirxml,error,exception,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,info,log,timeStamp,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,trace,warn".split(","),a;a=d.pop();){b[a]=b[a]||c}})((function(){try
        {console.log();return window.console;}catch(err){return window.console={};}})());
        // Set up SWF Address
        var flashvars = {
        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            scale: "noScale",
            allowFullscreen: "true",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            bgcolor: "#000000",
            wmode: "transparent" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
        };
        var attributes = {
            id:"YourEmbeddedSwf"
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "YourEmbeddedSwf.swf", 
            "altContent", "520", "724", "10.0.0", 
            "expressInstall.swf", 
            flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
// Load Facebook API
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({ appId: 'PLACE YOUR APP ID HERE', 
            channelUrl : '//yoursite.com/channel.html',
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true});
    // Additional initialization code here
  };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));

   // Custom Facebook Calls.
   // Call getAccessToken() from flash using External Interface,
    function getAccessToken(){
       FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
         var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
         //Log your access token so you can be sure the javascript is worjking,.
         console.log('Access Token = '+ access_token);
          var swf = document.getElementById("YourEmbeddedSwf");
          // Call a flash function exposed with External Interface.
          swf.setAccessToken(access_token);
         });
       } else {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
       }
     }, {scope: ''});
   }
    // Get Swf 
    function getSwf(movieName) {
         if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
             return window[movieName];
         } else {
             return document[movieName];
         }
     }
    }
</script> 
<!-- Embed the swf -->
<div id="altContent">
  <h1>Alternate Content</h1>
  <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Adobe Flash player</a></p>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just about you have to set your domain and canvas URL right in your application settings. Otherwise, you won't be able to see any errors when facebook.init() runs and it won't get into that function.